# Rx-Swift Clean architecture

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, clean-architecture

I want to design my swift app using clean architecture.

I have read the link below on clean architecture for swift

http://clean-swift.com/blog/

I have used these templates to create the app.

I wanted to ask if this is the best architecture to use as I want to code using Rx-Swift.

Also I would appreciate if someone could point out a few working examples for clean architecture with reactive swift.

Is using  Uncle Bob’s Clean Architecture for swift(http://clean-swift.com/blog/) a best practise for RxSwift or should I go with MVVM architecture

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi I'm using rxswift with clean architecture recently project

In my case, I use them in Profile scene especially looks like instagram

[image]

use case of profile scene

- user should refresh profile scene
- user should chance photo's category
- user should load more photo's like pagination

problem is, user can change post's category rapidly then

last fetched post's should be different to selected category :(

all event cause event asyncronousely

so I use rxswift

In Interactor has profileWorker(to fetch profile and category's post count), postWorke(to fetch posts)

and create three rxswift `PublishSubject` like
- rxCategory
- rxProfile
- rxPosts

Step is like below

`Interactor` subscribe `rxCategory`

`ViewController` request category change to `Interactor`

`Interactor` cause event `rxCategory.on(Event<Category>.next(category))`

`Interactor` using rxswift's flatMapLatest request posts with selected Category to postsWorker

```
rxCategory.asObservable().flatMapLatest{ (category) -> Observable<[Posts]> in
            return self.postsWorker.rxFetchPosts(requestModel, category: category)
        }.subscribe { (event) in
                if let posts = event.element {
                    self.updatePosts(posts)
                }
        }
 }
```

`PostsWorker` request `Observable<[Posts]>` to PostService (request to server using `Alamofire` and `SwiftyJSON`)

then `PostService` return `Observable<Posts>` then worker return to interactor

`Interactor` subscribe `PostsWorker`'s Observable and update posts , this cause `rxPosts`s event accur

`Interactor` subscribe `rxProfile` and `rxPosts` using combineLatest

and request presenting combined response to `Presentor`

```
Observable.combineLatest(rxProfile, rxPosts) { (e1, e2) -> ProfileResponse in

            return ProfileResponse(profile: e1, posts: e2)

            }.subscribe { (event: Event<ProfileResponse>) in
                self.output.presentProfile(event.element!)
        }
 }
```

this is my example using rxswift + clean swift architecture

in this situation, if user tap `FOOD` category and worker fetch many posts

and user tap `PLACE` category and fetch small posts then sometimes

although user tap people category. food posts fetched after people's posts

so I use rxswift to match correctly to selected category using flatMapLatest [ReativeX - FlatMapLatest](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html)

this can fetch and present to `Presentor` latest category's posts

rxswift known useful in `MVVM` architecture.

but I think it's up to you how can use them

thank you for reading :)

Comment: Can you please suggest how I should have my project structure according to mvvm architecture. Is there an Xcode template? Also could you provide some useful links

Comment: @A.S this is todo project using `Rxswift + MVVM architecture` https://github.com/devxoul/RxTodo i hope this project help you

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I see a lot of posts talking about Uncle Bob's clean architecture for swift. So which is RxSwift best practise? MVVM or the latter.

Comment: In Rxswift+MVVM, V bind to ViewModel when event occur viewModel subscribe it and update view automatically it looks good
If you use clean swift architecture, you can work same thing using Interactor 
think more about it Interactor + Presentor works like MVVM’s ViewModel abstractly
Interactor works small business logic using worker.

Comment: I like using clean swift architecture template, but sometimes use apple's default mvc architecture when make login, simple popup and tutorial scene because using clean architecture have no benefit. i think situationally use differenct architecture is important, and clean swift architecture help to create complicated scene

Comment: @Cruz shall you give me the sample ios app? which has uncle bob clean architecture + RxSwift